# How to check some change in the Dashboard(Service) and receive the result and perform action accordingly in Mobile App?

Tags: android, rest, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, instant-messaging

I have a requirement something like if the password get changed/User get deleted from the server then on immediate action I should logout from the Mobile Application, I am using Rest Services as back end. The service communication is with Android and iOS Mobile App as Front end.

How to know some operation got reflected in the service which should be like a GCM Service ?

As of now my approach is like for every 5/10 second time interval I am going to hit a service which will give me the updated result so that I can perform some action in my Mobile App, which I feel not a good approach. So I would like to know any best solutions to implement the same.

Looking for some good approach to follow, Thanks.